# How do I check if a field is empty or null in a text file using awk and bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting, suse

I have two text files and I want to compare their correspondent values according to their rows and columns. Each value (field) in the text file is separated by tabs.

Here are the files:

file1.txt

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  
-----------------------
row1  1     4     7        
row2  2     5     8         
row3  3     6     9
```

file2.txt

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  
-----------------------
row2  1     4     11        
row1  2     5     12
row3  3          9
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
awk '
FNR < 2 {next}                       
FNR == NR {           
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        a[i,$1] = $i;      
    }              
    next;       
}

# only compare if a row in file2 exists in file1
($1 in b) {                                          
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
    {
        if (a[i,$1] == $i) 
        {
             print "EQUAL"       
        }
        else if ( //condition that checks if value is null// )
        {
             print "NULL" 
        }
        else
        {
             print "NOT EQUAL"
        }
    }
}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

I am having difficulties with checking if there is a null value (`row3` and `col2` in `file2.txt`) in `file2.txt`. I don't even get an output for that null value. So far I tried `if ($i == "")` and it is still not giving me any output. Any suggestions? Thanks. (I'm using gnu awk in a bash script)

Let me know if further explanation is required.

Comment: @EdMorton I already mentioned that the values (or fields) in each text file is separated by tabs in the question! Its in the first paragraph of the question.

Comment: So you did, I didn't notice that, I just saw that your script wasn't using tabs as the separators.

Comment: @EdMorton Doesn't `awk` check for tabulation automatically?

Comment: If you mean does awk use tabs as the field separator by default - no, it uses any sequence of contiguous white-space characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the FS to tab:

```
awk -F'\t' '....'
```

Comment: Should I have the following condition to check if a filed is null: `if ($i == "") {//do something}`?

Comment: The problem I am getting now is that there might be extra tabulations after the last field in each row. So there are extra outputs that should not be happening. How do I fix that?

Comment: @Alias: Remove the extra tabs. Each tab means there is an additional field. AWK can't tell where you think a tab is a field and where it isn't. You could strip lines at the end but how about missing values for `Col3`, then?